# Filtering report results in SSRS in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools

I haven't needed to edit reports in several months, so I'm not sure specifically when the below behavior changed. I'm on Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 Professional with the latest version of [SSDT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx) as of this post (April 2016, 14.0.60413.0). The situation is the same in Visual Studio 2013 Update 5.

I have a database with a ton of information in it for various products. I'm trying to use SSDT (report designer) in VS to filter down to only retrieve a single result for a report on a given product in the table, but this doesn't appear to be possible.

In previous versions of SSDT in Visual Studio, I was able to right-click a dataset and edit the query manually. I would `SELECT` the columns I wanted, then I could add my own `WHERE` clause to filter by a report parameter. I cannot do this anymore--the options no longer exist. I can edit the query manually, but only at the level of the data source. That isn't helpful because the data source has no concept of a parameter to filter by, only the report does. [This MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255287.aspx) is incorrect here, see the screenshot below.

What is the correct way to retrieve only a single result for (or filter in general) a given dataset in SSDT/Visual Studio report designer?

Dataset properties (field names redacted):

[image: dataset properties]

Comment: Do you already have a parameter like `@Param` in your dataset query? Also, have you looked in your parameter properties?

Answer (score 1):

There are only two ways in which to retrieve only a single result.

1. Within SQL Server restrict your data using a WHERE clause or similar concept (INNER JOIN etc etc)
2. within SSRS restrict your data using a parameter

These are the *only* methods.